# A error: Use “truffle” to deploy the smart contract to testrpc

Tags: truffle, testrpc

The version used is as follows:
Truffle v5.1.61 (core: 5.1.61)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.4
Web3.js v1.2.9
EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3

Before "truffle migrate", I modified the "truffle-config.js" file to:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // 匹配任何network id
    }
  }
};
```

Then, enter the command "testrpc" to start a blockchain network:
[image]

Enter the command "truffle migrate", it shows that it failed：
[image]

, and the testrpc network crashed:
[image]

I don't understand what is happening here.

Comment: Testrpc was deprecated many years ago. Now the package is called `ganache-cli`. Also sometimes ethereum stack doesn't work  well with recent node versions, if they keep failing try a LTS version.

Comment: Thanks, get it. I've used ganache. The graphical interface it provides is really friendly.